# failure to boot new installation

Tags: boot

I've just downloaded ubuntu and transferred it to a memory stick. I pressed restart as per guide and the computer restarted -- in Windows10. It seems like an impasse. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

You computer BIOS seems to be booting from your previously set drive partition. You should force the BIOS to use the usb stick to boot, which is generally possible with a special key during boot such as F8 or F10 or F12 or Esc or Del, depending on your computer motherboard. Hit your defined key before the BIOS starts (probably a second after you power your computer from complete power-off).

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you created a bootable USB drive using UNetbootin or a similar program?
2. If you cant get into you're BIOS, insert the USB while running Windwos, hold shift while you click on restart. You should be able to choose to boot from USB or be able to get into BIOS from here.
3. search on the web for how to get into BIOS/Bootmenu for you're device.

good luck!